# Unable to load image if there is '/' in name in Flutter

Tags: flutter, path

I am struggling to get an image from app's documents directory. The image is called '10 sept 202316/32/57'. And when I am trying to fetch it, I get this error:

> Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '.../10 sept 202316/32/57'

It seems that Flutter considers '/10 sept 202316' and '/32' in the name of file as paths to subdirectories which is not the case. I wonder if there is a way to explain Flutter that those are actually parts of the file name?

P.S: Dunno if it matters, but the image is originally saved from the same App written on Swift (which I am currently rewriting on Flutter). And in Swift original file name was '10 sept 202316:32:57, but for some reason when it's saved to app's directory all ':' are changed to '/'

Comment: Yeah, when macos 10 was introduced, one of the weird things was the symmetrical mapping between : and / in filenames, depending on which view you were using (command line, Finder, cocoa apps, X11, and so on).  Best to stay away from *either* of those chars using macos.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a bit about this issue,

Having special chars in file names is often not recommended, especially because those characters might have some unwanted side effects depending on the programming language we are using, and in the specific case of the `/` character, it means different things depending on the Operating System, or environment that is running your application.

Notice that a `/` in a web application represents a **subroute** for the path, in **Linux** means it's a subdirectory, while in Windows the same char for that is the inverted bar `\`, which is also used to **escape reserved characters** in a lot of programming languages.

```
// Comment Example:
/* Multi-line comment Example */
\n -> new line
\t -> tab space
print(" This is an \" escaped quote")
```

There are some recent bug-tracking issues regarding [using special chars in file names](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111020) for Flutter, which might or might not be related to your issue.

If you'd like, try to escape the problematic character from the file names.
If you are using strings for the file names, try to escape the problematic chars from the file name string, by **replacing** `/` **with** `\/`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a workaround. Loop through all files in directory looking for the one containing '10 sept 202316/32/57'